# Disable & Activate Buttons | PyCord

Tags: discord, discord.py, pycord

I have a "Close ticket" button, a "Claim" button and a "Exit" button. Only the user who has also pressed the claim button can press the ticket unclaim button.

How do I make it so that the ticket unclaim button is deactivated by default and is now clickable when the user has pressed the claim button? I would also like the Claim button to be deactivated directly and only reactivated or made clickable when the user has pressed the Ticket Unclaim button again.

My Code:

```py
class TicketViewButtonEmMSG(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)
        self.claimed_by = None


    @discord.ui.button(
        label='Ticket schließen',
        emoji='<:AC_JavaScript:1058484252594929856>',
        style=discord.ButtonStyle.grey,
        custom_id='close'
    )
    async def callback1(self, button, interaction):

        emClose = discord.Embed(
            title='<:AC_JavaScript:1058484252594929856> - TICKET SCHLIEßEN',
            description=f'{interaction.user.mention}, wähle bitte einen Grund zur (Ticket-)Schließung aus.',
            color=0x2b2c30
        )
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=emClose, view=CloseDropdown(), ephemeral=True)


    @discord.ui.button(
        label='Ticket claimen',
        emoji='<:AC_Mauszeiger:1058472762290753639>',
        style=discord.ButtonStyle.grey,
        custom_id="ClaimTicket"
    )
    async def callback(self, button, interaction):
        member = interaction.user
        guild = interaction.guild
        staffRole = interaction.guild.get_role(905829680811216979)
        
        if staffRole in member.roles:
            ClaimEm = discord.Embed(
                title='<:AC_Ordner:1058480497614930001> - TICKET GECLAIMT',
                description=f'<:AC_PunktPink:1035563260377837639> Dein **Ticket** wurde von {member.mention} **geclaimt**.',
                color=0x2b2c30
            )
            await interaction.response.send_message(embed=ClaimEm)
            button.disabled = True
            self.claimed_by = member.id
            await interaction.message.edit(view=self)

        else:
            Err = discord.Embed(
                title=f'<:AC_Nope:1060555374815629362> - Fehler!',
                description=f'<:AC_PunktPink:1035563260377837639> Du kannst dein eigenes Ticket **nicht claimen**!',
                color=0x2b2c30
            )
            await interaction.response.send_message(embed=Err, ephemeral=True)


    @discord.ui.button(
        label='Ticket unclaimen',
        emoji='<:AC_Join:1060566086107533392>',
        style=discord.ButtonStyle.grey,
        custom_id='UnclaimTicket'
    )
    async def callback2(self, button, interaction):
        member = interaction.user
        guild = interaction.guild
        staffRole = interaction.guild.get_role(905829680811216979)

        if self.claimed_by == member.id:
            await interaction.response.send_message('Dieses ticket ist nun nicht mehr geclaimt.')
            self.claimed_by = None

        else:
            await interaction.response.send_message("Du kannst diesen Button leider nicht benutzen. Du musst zuerst dieses Ticket claimen.")
```

I have already created a `update_buttons` method.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have a couple of buttons like this. `Button 1` is disabled by default. Let's say when we press `Button 2` we want to disable it and enable `Button 1`. I think that covers the use cases you wanted.

```py
@discord.ui.button(
    label="Button 1",
    style=discord.ButtonStyle.grey,
    disabled=True,
    custom_id="one"
)
async def button_one_callback(self, button, interaction):
    pass

@discord.ui.button(
    label="Button 2",
    style=discord.ButtonStyle.grey,
    custom_id="two"
)
async def button_two_callback(self, button, interaction):
    
    # start by disabling ourself
    button.disabled = True

    # all the view's children are accessible via `self.children`
    for child in self.children:
        # check it's a child we want to disable
        # could also check "label" attribute or "emoji" if you wanted
        # or custom_ids aren't applicable
        if type(child) == discord.ui.Button and child.custom_id == "one"
            child.disabled = True
            # break so we're not looping over unnecessarily
            break

    # remember to edit the message with the new view
    await interaction.message.edit(view=self)
```

Instead of the `for` loop that iterates over the children, you could use indexing to access the right buttons here instead, so:

```py
button_one = self.children[0]
button_one.disabled = True
```

This does rely on the ordering remaining the same. My views tend to be quite dynamic and there's a lot of adding buttons/selects as users interact so I found that iterating over and checking labels/custom_ids was more reliable at making sure I was disabling/changing the right UI elements.

The [`View`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/ui_kit.html#discord.ui.View) object.
The [`Button`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/ui_kit.html#discord.ui.Button) object.
The [pycord guide](https://guide.pycord.dev/interactions/ui-components/buttons) pages on UI and buttons.

This should hopefully give you what you need to adapt it for your own needs.

Answer (score -1):

### It's as simple as:

If you want to disable all items from a view from a button:

```
button.view.disable_all_items()
```

If you want to disable an item from a button:

```
button.disabled = True
```

See below how to access button. The parameter `disabled` is defaulted to false. You can set this to true and disable said button.

### If you want to deactivate a button by default:

```
    @discord.ui.button(
    label='Ticket unclaimen',
    emoji='<:AC_Join:1060566086107533392>',
    style=discord.ButtonStyle.grey,
    custom_id='UnclaimTicket', 
    disabled=True
    )
```

You can set disabled to true when creating a button.

### How do I get other buttons in a view?

You can use the

```
view.children
```

and index to get other buttons. `view.children` returns a list of items from the view. See [here](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/ui_kit.html#discord.ui.View.children).

[Docs](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/ui_kit.html#discord.ui.Button)

Comment: Some of this is incorrect; `self` is **not** the button in the code that OP has given us but it **is** the `view`. `self.view.disable_all_items()` and `self.disabled = True` will throw errors. It should be `self.disable_all_items()` from the callback and `button.disabled = True`.

Comment: @ESloman it was example code from another project. I explained it should have been the button.

Comment: Perhaps I was too keen on the downvote, but I wasn't expecting you to write it for them. I just think that using the examples with `self` would perhaps be confusing for users who are new to Python and/or discord stuff.

Comment: @ESloman I completely understand. I’ll try to edit my post accordingly.