# how do disable a button after using

Tags: python, pycord

```
import discord
from discord.ui import Button, View
from datetime import datetime
from load_config import load_config
from core.utils import Utilies

class claim(discord.ui.Button):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        super().__init__(label='Claim Ticket [FAST]', style=discord.ButtonStyle.grey, emoji="⚠", custom_id='claim-button')
        self.bot = bot

    async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        member = interaction.user
        channel = interaction.channel
        guild = interaction.guild

        if not member.guild_permissions.manage_messages:
            await interaction.followup.send('You are not allowed to claim tickets.', ephemeral=True)
            return

        overwrites = channel.overwrites

        
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title='Claimed Ticket Successful!',
            description=f"Ticket has been claimed by {member.mention}",
            color=discord.Color.green(),
            timestamp=datetime.now()
        )
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
```

what I can do here? please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable & Activate Buttons | PyCord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75510331/disable-activate-buttons-pycord)

Answer (score 1):

To disable a button, you can use `button.disabled = True`. In this case, it would be `self.disabled = True`.

You can use `interaction.message` to receive the message that the view is attached to. Then, you can edit the message with `message.edit`.

However, you need a `discord.ui.View` object, but you can get that with `button.view`.

So overall, your code should look something like so.

```py
self.disabled = True

await interaction.message.edit(view = self.view)
```

Sources:

https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/ui_kit.html#discord.ui.Button

https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/models.html#discord.Interaction.message

https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/models.html#discord.Message.edit